# Call process running on Ubuntu localhost in python

Tags: python, ubuntu, localhost, subprocess

I have almost no experience with Linux, but I have a service running on my Ubuntu machine, that translates a string from one language to another language.
The service can be used like this `echo "som input text" | nc 127.0.0.1 3333`, which outputs the translation of "some input text".
Now, I want to use this service in a Python program I am developing, but I have no idea how to do this. I am also concerned about giving a very long text as input. Is there a restriction on input length? I am thinking about stripping the input text for quotes (`"`), to not cause any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect to a TCP/IP service, you need to open a [socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket). This is not (too much) OS dependent and this is supported by all major operating systems.

Adapted [from the Python socket module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example):

```
# Echo client program
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'    # The host
PORT = 3333              # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.sendall('Hello, world')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print 'Received', repr(data)
```

Concerning a potential restriction on the input length -- this will be totally dependent of your service. Python shouldn't impose you any practical limit here beyond the available memory.